# Can't install cordova with npm 5.6.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, cordova, npm

I can't install cordova in my Linux (deepin 15.5), please help me :)

**$ sudo npm install -g ionic**

```
/usr/local/bin/ionic -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic  
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/ionic/node_modules/fsevents):  
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

\+ ionic@3.19.0
updated 1 package in 8.52s
```

**$sudo npm install -g cordova**

```
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead  
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules  /npm/node_modules/ansistyles  
npm ERR! code ENOENT  
npm ERR! errno -2  
npm ERR! syscall rename  
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansistyles' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.ansistyles.DELETE'  
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.  
npm ERR! enoent  

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-12-08T19_53_31_209Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try downgrading your NPM version. Personally, I had some issues with 5.6.0 and had to downgrade to 5.3.0, haven't had a problem with any packages since then.

If you want to, this is how you'd downgrade your version to 5.3.0:

```
npm install -g npm@5.3.0
```

Cheers!

EDIT: Also, make sure there have not been any previous installations of the package you are trying to install. Leftovers or older versions may cause conflict which might not let you install/update to newer versions.

Try this, if the previous solution doesn't work:

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

Struggled for hours trying to uninstall and reinstall npm/node, with different versions and so on, but what finally did the work (without downgrading from 5.6.0) was as @Sairo Guanipa mentiond:

npm uninstall -g cordova

npm install -g cordova

From here on all worked fined (cordova/windows for me)